# Why is my click event not registering after clicking to sort a WebGrid?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a webgrid with a search button. It works fine if I search first, it updates the webgrid with the results. If I click a header and sort the grid, my search button doesn't register anymore and I cant figure out how to fix it.

This is the view

```
@{

var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: false, canSort: true,
selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "CurrentGrid");
}

<script>
$("._container").on('click',"#searchCurrentBTTN", function (e) {
    alert("ok");
    var url = '@Url.Action("Current")';
$.get(url, { searchTerm: $("#SearchCurrent").val() }, function   (result) {

        $('#CurrentGrid').html(result);
    });
});

</script>
<div>
<div class="IndexGridDiv" id="CurrentGrid">
    <div class="_container">
        <label>Search :  </label><input type="text" name="searchString" id="SearchCurrent">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchCurrentBTTN" />
    </div>
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
        headerStyle: "header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        footerStyle: "footer",
        selectedRowStyle: "select",
        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("ID", "ID"),
        grid.Column("Balloon", "Balloon"),

 ))

</div>
```

Comment: Could it be that the sorting method recreates the grid and thence removes your click event handler?

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure that's what is going on, just not sure how to re- registrar it

Comment: I added ajaxUpdateCallback: "callBack" to the webgrid and duplicated the on click function in a function called callBack(). It seems to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your grid content in a separate div tag and then update that html. Currently you're delegating the click event to an element that is replaced on search submit response (`._container`):

**HTML/RAZOR**

```
<!--SNIP -->
<div id='gridContent'> <!-- HERE wrapper! -->
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
        headerStyle: "header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        footerStyle: "footer",
        selectedRowStyle: "select",
        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("ID", "ID"),
        grid.Column("Balloon", "Balloon"),
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("._container").on('click',"#searchCurrentBTTN", function (e) {
    alert("ok");
    var url = '@Url.Action("Current")';
$.get(url, { searchTerm: $("#SearchCurrent").val() }, function   (result) {

        $('#gridContent').html(result); // <--- HERE
    });
});
```